# Что такое сборка в .NET?

Tags: .net, assembly

Что такое сборка в .net?
Вот, например, я так понимаю, .exe или .dll  файлы- это сборки. Подключать пространства имен можно только из тех сборок, которые были подключены, верно?
Тогда почему Рихтер пишет, что в mscorlib.dll содержатся все базовые типы FCL, то есть string object int и т.д, то есть по сути содержится BCL, но при этом я все равно могу подключать пространство имен System.Text.RegularExpressions. Или Рихтер имел ввиду, что в той сборке содержатся все типы FCL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Что такое сборка в .net? Вот, например, я так понимаю, .exe или .dll файлы- это сборки

Сборка - это логическая структурная единица .NET приложений. Обычно сборка действительно представляет из себя один EXE или DLL файл, но в общем случае может состоять и из нескольких файлов. См. [Содержимое сборок](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assembly-contents)

> Подключать пространства имен можно только из тех сборок, которые были подключены, верно?

Да

> Тогда почему Рихтер пишет, что в mscorlib.dll содержатся все базовые типы FCL, то есть string object int и т.д, то есть по сути содержится BCL, но при этом я все равно могу подключать пространство имен System.Text.RegularExpressions

Не очень понятен вопрос. Вроде не врет Рихтер, а System.Text.RegularExpressions содержится в сборке System.dll.

Comment: А, может быть это вижуал студио автоматически добавляет. Просто Рихтер пишет что автоматически добавлена только mscorlib.dll

Comment: То есть FCL это какой-то набор типов, но это не сборка, не пространство имен или что-то подобное. Что такое FCL в таком случае? Это совокупность сборок?

Comment: @МаркПавлович при создании проекта в студии ссылка на System.dll несомненно автоматически добавляется. Отличие  mscorlib в том, что она добавлена неявно, и ее никак нельзя удалить через интерфейс студии (хотя ее можно отключить параметром компилятора, если требуется использовать нестандартную mscorlib)

Comment: @МаркПавлович Да, FCL - это набор стандартных типов. В текущей реализации .NET это действительно несколько сборок.